# Сортировка массива объектов по значениям свойств. Синтаксис получения доступа к значениям свойств объектов в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

Есть код для сортировки массива объектов по значению свойств объектов:

```
     function byField (field) {
        return function (a, b) {
            return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;
        };
    }
    var users = [{
    name: "Вася",
    surname: 'Иванов',
    age: 20
    }, {
    name: "Петя",
    surname: 'Чапаев',
    age: 25
    }, {
    name: "Маша",
    surname: 'Медведева',
    age: 18
    }];
    alert(byField);

    users.sort(byField('name'));
    users.forEach(function(user) {
    alert( user.name );
    });
```

Объясните пожалуйста синтаксис `a[field]`. Что это значит?
Массив `а` и индексом элемента `field`?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас свойство задается в переменной, как в данном случае в переменной `field`, то вы не можете записать выражение

```
a.field
```

где `a` - это объект, так как в объявленных объектах нет свойства с именем `field`. Поэтому для указания свойств через переменные применяется следующий синтаксис

```
a[field]
```

Для соритровки массива объектов требуется сравнивать попарно элементы массива. Для этого в вызове метода `sort` используется функция

```
function (a, b) {
            return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;
        };
```

которая возвращает результат сравнения двух объектов.

Эту функцию методу `sort` предоставляет выражение `byField('name')`, то есть функция, которая и возвращает указанную функцию сравнения. Но при этом функция сравнения будет вызываться в контексте функции `byField`, а потому будет иметь доступ к переменной `field`. Это так называемый прием замыкания в JS.

Comment: @AlexanderKorinskiy Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Владислав, за подробное объяснение сути происходящего. Замыкания, не простая тема.

Answer (score 0):

`a` - это не массив, а объект.

`a[field]` - обращение к свойству, имеющему имя, сохранённой в `field`.

Comment: Вот так я затупил. Спасибо, добрый человек. Пошел перечитывать главу про объекты.